# Prove that $\frac{1}{kn} + \frac{1}{kn + 1} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{kn + n - 1} > n \left(\sqrt[n]{\frac{k+1}{k}} - 1 \right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, contest-math

> Let $k,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ with $n >  1$. Prove that $$\frac{1}{kn}  + \frac{1}{kn + 1} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{kn + n - 1} > n \left(\sqrt[n]{\frac{k+1}{k}} - 1 \right)$$

I roughly observe that AM-GM can be used so
I tried that $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{kn + j} + n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1}\frac{kn^2 + jn + 1}{kn + j}$$

but I am stuck how to proceed.

Comment: I wonder if the second fraction should be $\frac{1}{kn + 1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea of using AM-GM inequality is right, but unfortunately your equation is wrong. It should be
$$\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{kn+j}\right)+n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{kn+j}+1\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{kn+j+1}{kn+j}$$ Then it should be easier for you to proceed from here, as we observe that $$\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{kn+j+1}{kn+j}=\frac{kn+n}{kn}=\frac{k+1}k$$